# symmetric posititve definite matrix

Tags: matrices, numerical-methods

I am trying to find all values for $\alpha$ and $\beta$ for which

$$ A(\alpha, \beta)= 
\left[
\begin{matrix}
3&0&-2\\\alpha&3&2\\-2&2&\beta 
\end{matrix}
\right]
$$

is symmetric positive definite.

I know that $A$ is symmetric if $A=A^T$, but how do I show that it is symmetric positive definite?

Answer (score 2):

Symmetry tells you what $\alpha$ should be.

[Sylvester's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion) is one way to check positive-definiteness, which will help you find what values of $\beta$ are valid.

Comment: so then with symmetry $\alpha = 0?$

Comment: I believe $\beta > \frac{8}{3}$?

Answer (score 0):

Compute the eigenvalues and choose $\beta$ that makes them all positive.